# Delete mysql row on click

Tags: php, mysql, post, sql-delete

Here is the link style

```
<a href='del-user.php?id={$row['username']}'>Delete</a>
```

{$row['username']} will grab the username field from the Admin-CMS users table

Now..... Here is what it will take you to when you click it:

```
del-user.php?id=billy
```

---

NOW FOR WHAT I AM ATTEMPTING

I want to read the link and delete the row with a username of billy

Here is my del-user.php file

```
<?php
  if($_GET['id'] != ""){
    $userID = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE username='".$userID."'";
    $query  = mysql_query($sql);
  }
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Btw my database setup is

```
TABLE   is called :     users
COLUMN  is called :     username
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to  XSRF and SQL injection!

Answer (score 0):

First off, [ESCAPE YOUR DATA](http://bobby-tables.com/). Or use prepared statements. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Second, don't use `mysql` libraries. They are depreciated. You need to use `mysqli` instead.

Third, where is your connection pointer? You need to have created one somewhere and pass it to your query function.

```
$con = mysqli_connect(...);
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Comment: I haven't gotten to securing it.... NEXT I've already connected don't worry, How else am I gathering the data successfully in the first place

Comment: Fair enough. Since you're doing this with a `GET`, are you making sure that your delete matches up perfectly? And I assume you're running `urlencode` on the username?

Comment: You gave the exampled of trying to delete `billy`. Are you sure there's a record that matches that entry?

Comment: *"I haven't gotten to securing it"* ... you don't secure it later.  You write it securely from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I have just ran a test on a server, albeit I had to edit to run in my environment, and it ran correctly.

The entire file I used was:

```
<?php
include_once('pre_load.php');
login_required();
$auth = Authentication::instance();
$db   = CDatabase::instance();

if(array_key_exists('id', $_GET) && !in_array($_GET['id'], array(0, ""))
{
    $userID = (is_string($_GET['id']) && ctype_digit($_GET['id'])) ? $_GET['id'] : FALSE ;
    if ($userID)
    {
        $sql    = "DELETE FROM `bans` WHERE `id` ='".$userID."'";
        $query  = $db->execute($sql);
        echo '<p>Row Deleted</p>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<p>Invalid ID</p>';
    }
}
?>
```

This all ran correctly, which leads me to this question:

Is that your entire file? If so, how are you connecting to the database to initiate the deletion?

The code, in itself, looks correct and I see no error, but the fact you posted it as your file, questions whether a database connection is included.

Include the DB connection in that file, if it isn't, and your problem will be over.

If the DB connection is, in fact, in the file, post here and I'll troubleshoot some more.